# How to turn off airplane mode?(12.10)

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

I have a problem get the WiFi to work in Ubuntu 12.10.
When I use gnome network manager it indicates that wireless is disabled by hardware switch while it is not.

In the Network Settings Panel in the wireless section, it only shows the hardware address and the switch is off and it's disabled so that I can't change the status to On.
At the bottom there is an airplane mode switch which is On, and turning it off has no effect and it immediately turns back on.
I use a sony vaio CA series Laptop

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Enter `rfkill unblock all` in Terminal and then try to enable wireless, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

My Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (project Sputnik) has Ubuntu 15.04. When I suspend & resume, the wifi is sometimes stuck in a "disabled" state and the status bar menu is also non-functional.  I found this to work best for me:

```
wifitoggle='nmcli r wifi off ; sleep 1 ; nmcli r wifi on'
```

This forces the wifi to turn off, then back on, and seems quite reliable.